# Angular mat-button-toggle focus overlay color

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-toggle-button-group in a form:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="mb-4">
  <mat-button-toggle-group
    name="carrier"
    aria-label="Choose Carrier"
    #carrierSelection="matButtonToggleGroup"
    formControlName="carrierChoice"
    [value]="carrierChosen"
  >
    <mat-button-toggle [value]="carrier" *ngFor="let carrier of carriers">
      <img alt="Carrier: {{ carrier | uppercase }}" src="/assets/sending/images/carriers/{{ carrier }}/tab-logo.svg" />
    </mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</form>
```

It insists on showing a heavy black border around the button when it is focused, via tab key or clicked.

[image]

I inspect the div `<div class="mat-button-toggle-focus-overlay"></div>` and find this:
[image]

So, first I tried this:

```
.mat-button-toggle-checked .mat-button-toggle-focus-overlay {
  border-bottom: 0 !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

No luck still a heavy black line, although inspecting it now shows my overrides:
[image]

Which I do not understand.

Next,  I try this:

```
.mat-button-toggle-focus-overlay,
.mat-button-focus-overlay {
  box-shadow: var(--focus_shadow) var(--focus);
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}
```

When I inspect the `<div class="mat-button-toggle-focus-overlay"></div>` in the app, it actually shows it has my styles:

[image]

But the black line persists.

Comment: Would it be possible to create stackblitz since I don't see it happening here: https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/examples

Comment: Chances are it's possibly a side-effect of the frameworks you're using. Seeing that you're using Bootstrap's CSS utilities, it's quite likely that Bootstrap is also theming your buttons to show a border on focus or when clicked on as the button toggle element actually uses buttons under-the-hood.

Comment: You're also not providing enough information regarding what you're using and all of the CSS (intentional or not) that is applied on the button toggle. Additionally, I suggest that you should try toggling the `:focus` pseudo-class selector to see what styles are being applied on the element.

Comment: Apparently,  Microsoft Edge Chromium changed their focus style (as did Chrome).  Firefox just shows its orange dotted line.  I'd prefer not to show focus on click, on for keyboard users. see https://web.dev/style-focus/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Chrome changed the focus treatment recently and Edge Chromium decided to use a heavy black line for focus.

so I wrapped the toggle group in a DIV and set this:

```
.carrier-toggle {
  .mat-button-toggle-label-content,
  .mat-button-toggle-button,
  .mat-button-toggle {
    outline: none !important;
  }
}
```

and then I set my own focus style, with a background color.

```
.mat-button-toggle,
.mat-button-toggle-group-appearance-standard .mat-button-toggle + .mat-button-toggle {

  &:focus {
    background-color: var(--rich200);
    border: 0;
  }
}
```